# How to get one character from RichTextBox C# WPF click a button and change the color of it

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I have a `RichTextBox` and a button. I want to get one char from the `RichTextBox` and change the color of it every time when user click the button.
I read a lot about `TextRange` but I can't do it in the right way.

```
var textentered = txtuser.Text.Substring(txtuser.SelectionStart-1, 1);
var tmptext = txtprogramtext.Substring(txtuser.SelectionStart-1, 1 );           
var rangeOfText1 = new TextRange(txtprogram.CaretPosition.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward),
                                 txtprogram.CaretPosition.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward));
```

Comment: You problem description does not clear enough. What do you mean _`one char from RichTextBox`_? Coloring manually selected text will help resolve your problem?

Comment: I'm sorry I mean one letter every button click one letter from richtextbox change to green or red

Answer (score 2):

The following code fragment colors one character in the `RichTextBox` from the current caret position:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Case 1: Color one character from the current caret position
    var startPosition = rtb.CaretPosition;
    // Forward to next character
    var endPosition = rtb.CaretPosition.GetPositionAtOffset(1, LogicalDirection.Forward);
    var tr = new TextRange(startPosition, endPosition);
    tr.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Red);
    rtb.CaretPosition = endPosition; // Forward the caret

    //// Case 2: The following line will color the current selected text
    //rtb.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Red);
}
```

The XAML:

```
<Window ... >
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RichTextBox Grid.Row="0" x:Name="rtb" AllowDrop="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Padding="2">
            <FlowDocument>
                <Paragraph FontSize="12"  TextAlignment="Left">
                    <Paragraph.Foreground>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="Blue"/>
                    </Paragraph.Foreground>
                    <Run Text="RichTextBox has built-in handling for the bubbling MouseUp and MouseDown events. " />
                </Paragraph>
                <Paragraph FontSize="12" TextAlignment="Left" >
                    <Paragraph.Foreground>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="Black"/>
                    </Paragraph.Foreground>
                    <Run Text="If you need to respond to these events, listen for the tunneling PreviewMouseUp and PreviewMouseDown events instead..." />
                </Paragraph>
            </FlowDocument>
        </RichTextBox>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Click="Button_Click">Color</Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```